# Creating a view filter

Tags: filter

I have a litle issue to create a view. Let me summarize the case.
There is a list with all the daily tasks, assigned to someone.
I would like to create a view that shows one the assigned task to "you", that needs to be handled today and that was not handled previously.

It should be something like: AssignedTo=[ME] AND (HandlingDate=[TODAY] OR Handled!="Yes")

I can not create it because I dont have the option (or most likely i dont know how) to add the brackets.

What I need is:

```
AssignedTo=[ME] AND (HandlingDate=[TODAY] OR Handled!="Yes")
```

What I got with SP Filter

```
AssignedTo=[ME] AND HandlingDate=[TODAY] OR Handled!="Yes"
```

You help is hardly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to make it HandlingDate=[TODAY] OR Handled!="Yes" and AssignedTo=[ME]?  Does that give the expected results?

If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to convert it to an XSLT data view in Sharepoint Designer so you can take advantage of the XSLT filtering.

Comment: Thanks Pirate, I will try it soon and will let you know.

Comment: No need for an XSLT data view.  Just pay attention to how each filter segment works.  Last segment needs to be an AND not an OR.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to create additional filters conditions, right? 
You might not find it, because it's too easy:

In the form where you create a view -in the "Filter" section, there is a link on the right saying "Show More Columns..." that is where you can add a new filter condition.

So you go like this:

- AssignedTo=[ME]
- Show More Columns... (select AND with the radio button)
- HandlingDate=[TODAY]
- Show More Columns... (select OR with the radio button)
- Handled!="Yes"

Comment: Thanks AlexPoint,

but by doing this my query will be
AssignetTo=[me] AND HandlingDate=[today] OR Handled!="Yes"
and not 
AssignetTo=[me] AND (HandlingDate=[today] OR Handled!="Yes")

Comment: Ok, I see -my fault. I dont have a solution for that. Sorry

Comment: AND/OR is confusing in SharePoint view filters. The simple answer is to change the OR to AND, since it is using a negative condition, and will therefore exclude the items that have already been handled. Sometimes we make things too hard for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this old question, the original issue can be solved by using

> AssignedTo is equal to [ME] AND HandlingDate is equal to [TODAY]
>   **AND** Handled is not equal to "Yes"

if you are creating the view in the browser. The "is not equal to" in the final filter segment serves to exclude any items that meet the first two segments of the query but have already been handled.